# Import image with Perl

Tags: image, perl, import

I know it sounds like a question that would have been already posted many times, but I can't find exactly what I need.

What I want is to extract the data of the image pixel by pixel. 
The import type would be .jpg (or another format if there is a function that doesn't work on jpeg).
The export type would be an array or a list of integers with the values of the pixels.

The function I am searching for is similar to "imread" for those who know Matlab.
I have tried the function "open" in Perl but then I don't know what type is the extracted image.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [Image::Magic](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Magick)

Comment: What kind of integer values? RGBs? You'd need three or four values for each pixel, depending on how many channels there are in your original format. JPEG has three of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Image::Magick](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Magick) to do this [like clamp suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581254/import-image-with-perl#comment105330292_59581254), but I like the more modern [Imager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Imager) package more.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Imager;

my $img = Imager->new( file => 'scratch/so.jpg' ) or die Imager->errstr;
print "X\tY\tR\tG\tB\n";
foreach my $x ( 0 .. $img->getwidth - 1 ) {
    foreach my $y ( 0 .. $img->getheight - 1 ) {
        my $color = $img->getpixel( x => $x, y => $y );
        my @rgb = $color->rgba;
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", $x, $y, @rgb[0,1,2]);
    }
}
```

This will output

```
X   Y   R   G   B
0   0   31  0   30
0   1   107 54  106
0   2   240 95  214
1   0   191 138 190
1   1   82  29  81
1   2   177 32  151
2   0   179 255 197
2   1   77  203 95
2   2   255 232 126
```

I've used this image: [image: 3x3 pixel colorful example image]

While the code looks a bit complicated, that's mostly to produce this output. The idea is simple. You iterate over each row, then over each column, and get the values for the pixels. RGBA in this case stands for red, green blue and the alpha channel, but a JPEG doesn't have an alpha channel (which is typically used for transparency, like in PNG or GIFs).

You will have to install Imager and [Imager::File::JPEG](https://metacpan.org/pod/Imager::File::JPEG), which requires `libjpeg` (`libjpeg-dev` on Ubuntu, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I would use GraphickMagic rather than ImageMagick as it is slow as hell compared to GM.